# How to fill up data table from different sheet basing on column value?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to incorporate such a workbook that contains large datatable in one sheet and different input sheet. As per header column's cell value, I want to fill up the database from input sheet. It is as below:

```
Sheet Database                                        Sheet Input
Date           Data                                   Date           Data
.                                                     12 May 14      45
.
.
.
10 May 14      16
11 May 14      85
12 May 14      45
13 May 14
14 May 14
15 May 14
.
.
.
.
```

While I am using the Data Column Cell's formula as an example in Cell B2 of "Sheet Database" sheet like:

IF(A2='Sheet Input'!$A$2,'Sheet Input'!$B$2)

Only the cell beside the date that matches with the input sheet, gets the value from the input sheet. The scenario is as follows:

```
Sheet Database                                        Sheet Input
Date           Data                                   Date           Data
.                                                     12 May 14      45
.
.
.
10 May 14      FALSE
11 May 14      FALSE
12 May 14      45
13 May 14      FALSE
14 May 14      FALSE
15 May 14      FALSE
.
.
.
.
```

But I want to persist the value once available. That means, I want to enter data from Input sheet and the database sheet should keep the value once it was entered. Input sheet may vary to data, but the previous data should be in the database sheet.

I know very well that this code will not be able to achieve my aim.

I am brainstorming, but could not find any way to do so. Can anybody please help me in this regard?

Note: I shall not use macro/VB. I solely want to be dependent on the built in functions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a simple `VLOOKUP`. Something like the following formula in the data column of your `Sheet Input` sheet should do the trick (Assuming the `data` column is column `B` and the `Date` column is column `A` and `Date` and `Data` are headers in row `1`):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet Database'!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

This function is essentially looking for the value in cell `A2` from `Sheet Input` in column `A` of `Sheet Database` and then returning the value in column `B` that corresponds to the value it was searching for.

If you want the cell with the formula to be blank in the event that the value is not found in the database, you can wrap your function with an `IFERROR` function as follows

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet Database'!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

Good luck.

Comment: Dear Nicholas,

Thank you so very much for your answer!

Actually The 'Sheet Database' is my target. I want to program there. The 'Sheet Input' is the sheet where user will give daily input. The code of the cell "A2" of 'Sheet Input' is "=TODAY()". And the cell B2 there is only where the user will give their input. I just want to preserve the daily inputs in 'Sheet Database'.

I hope I could make myself clear dear Nicholas. It is just like data entry in 'Sheet Input' Sheet, and preserving the daily data in 'Sheet Database'.

Have a nice day and take care!

regards.